# angularjs: Creating system for flashing messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My *AngularJS* app has the following simplified behavior:

I created a *Services* module with a factory called `server`. This `server` module handles my communication to a websocket server. When an event occurs within this websocket connection, I want to show a flashing message in my `MainController`.

My service:

```
return function init() {
  ws = new WebSocket(...);
  ws.onopen(function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("flash", "websocket connected");
  });
};
```

My view:

```
<article ng-controller=MainController ng-init=init()>
  <section ng-show="flash.length > 0">
    <p ng-repeat="message in flash">
      {{ message }}
    </p>
  <section>
  <section ng-view>
  ...
</article>
```

My controller:

```
function MainController ($rootScope, $scope, server) {
  $scope.init = function () {
    $scope.flash = [];
    server.init(); 
  };
  $scope.on("flash", function (event, flash) {
    $scope.flash.push(flash);
    // $scope.$apply("$scope.flash"); <-- if I uncomment this line, I get the error...
    console.debug($scope.flash[$scope.flash.length -1]);
  });
};
```

If I run this code, I get the debug message on websocket connection, but the changes to the `flash` array are applied only, if I click a button f.e. or if I call the `$apply` function.
The latter results in an error that an "apply is already in progress". After some research I'm sure, that the call to `$apply` is not necessary.

So: how to alter the `flash` array in a way which informs the view immediately about changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you DO need `$apply` to be called from the WebSocket code.  The WebSocket event is happening outside of Angular, so it is necessary.  If your `$apply` is resulting in the message that a digest is already in process, is it possible that some other code is also sending a "flash" message?

I recommend you put the `$apply` call in your WebSocket code:

```
return function init() {
  ws = new WebSocket(...);
  ws.onopen(function () {

    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("flash", "websocket connected");
    });

  });
};
```

**Extra**

If you really need to put the `$apply` in your controller (I don't recommend this), then you can try the "safe apply" pattern:

```
$scope.$safeApply = function (fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```

Then, when you receive your "flash" event, you can just do this:

```
$scope.$safeApply(function() {
  $scope.flash.push(flash);
});
```

Again, I think this approach is putting the knowledge of `$apply` in the wrong place, but it IS possible to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you for quick answering. Calling `$apply` in my websocket service works and I think, this is better than my `$timeout` solution below.

Comment: Yes, this is a much better solution than the `$timeout` solution and here is why:  It doesn't rely on side affects of `$timeout` to work.  `$timeout` is designed to call your code later.  `$apply` is designed to run a `$digest` cycle. The approach in this answer is the way `$apply` is meant to be used, and is THE way to tell angular to run a `$digest` cycle from outside of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in a related [so-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799881/angular-js-view-not-being-updated-after-receiving-message-from-broadcast?rq=1).
So I've wrapped the call to `$broadcast` into a `$timeout`.

```
$timeout(function () {
  $rootScope.$broadcast("flash", "websocket connected"); 
}, 50);
```

*Please leave a comment If you know, why this works!*

Comment: Two reasons come to mind. $timeout does an apply when it is done, so if the problem was that you needed to $apply then that solved it for you. Secondly a timeout will push anything inside it to the next "cycle" in angular (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts), so if it is a timing issue that might be the reason. (the last one might only apply to setTimeout, not $timeout, not sure)